# How to transfer live camera feeds over WIFI or Bluetooth

Tags: ios, objective-c, video-streaming, gamekit, multipeer-connectivity

What i am trying to achieve.

1. Connect multiple iPhones over same wi-fi. (using game kit, this can be achieve)
2. Now i need to transfer camera feeds to connected iPhones.

I have seen so many samples and tutorials for transfer files (using game kit) but here i need to transfer live feeds to other iPhones without/minimum lag.

Can this be achieve using game kit approach?

Can any one give me the direction so that i can improve my research in this domain.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yea..

There is a MultipeerConnectivity framework which provides this functionality!

Have a look in this sample.

https://github.com/pj4533/AVCaptureMultipeerVideoDataOutput

Follow the steps as it has 2 different projects.

One connects the devices and transfer streams and the other project shows live feeds coming from that in a collectionView.

Enjoy!